# Coaleseing a dataframe by removing Nan values

Tags: python

This is a dataframe that I generate based on the data I have coming in

```
data = {'col2': ['Previous Sale', 'Price', 'OR Book-Page','Qualification Description','','',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
        'col3': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'03/24/2015', 210000, '00000-00000', 'Sales which are qualified','','',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
        'col4': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'08/03/1995', 121000, '00000-00000', 'Sales which are qualified','','']}

dframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need to transform dataframe to look like this instead

```
data2 = {'Previous Sale': ['03/24/2015', '08/03/1995'],
        'Price': [ 210000, 121000],
        'OR Book-Page': [ '00000-00000', '00000-00000'],
        'Qualification Description': ['Sales which are qualified','Sales which are qualified'],
        'col0': ['',''],
        'col1': ['','']
        }

dframeFix = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

How could I make this transformation programmatically.
The last 2 columns are blank because they dont always have data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'col2': ['Previous Sale', 'Price', 'OR Book-Page', 'Qualification Description', '', '', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'col3': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '03/24/2015', 210000, '00000-00000', 'Sales which are qualified', '', '', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'col4': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '08/03/1995', 121000, '00000-00000', 'Sales which are qualified', '', '']
}

dframe = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a dictionary to store the transformed data
data2 = {}

# Iterate over each column in the original DataFrame
for col in dframe.columns:
    # Get the values for the current column
    values = dframe[col].values
    
    # Check if the column is one of the blank columns
    if col in ['col0', 'col1']:
        # Assign an empty list to the corresponding key in the dictionary
        data2[col] = [''] * len(values)
    else:
        # Assign the non-null values to the corresponding key in the dictionary
        data2[col] = [value for value in values if pd.notnull(value)]
        
# Create the transformed DataFrame
dframeFix = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# Transpose the DataFrame to match the desired format
dframeFix = dframeFix.transpose()

# Reset the column names and set the first row as the header
dframeFix.columns = dframeFix.iloc[0]
dframeFix = dframeFix[1:]

# Reset the index
dframeFix.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(dframeFix)
```

Output:

```
col2 Previous Sale   Price OR Book-Page  Qualification Description    
0       03/24/2015  210000  00000-00000  Sales which are qualified    
1       08/03/1995  121000  00000-00000  Sales which are qualified
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to fix the root cause of this problem - how the initial dataframe is generated. If there isn't fix you can try:

```py
dframe = (
    dframe.apply(lambda x: sorted(x, key=lambda k: pd.isna(k)))
    .dropna()
    .set_index("col2")
    .T.reset_index(drop=True)
)
dframe.columns.name = None

print(dframe)
```

Prints:

```
  Previous Sale   Price OR Book-Page  Qualification Description    
0    03/24/2015  210000  00000-00000  Sales which are qualified    
1    08/03/1995  121000  00000-00000  Sales which are qualified
```